# Menu opens up even mouse is away

Tags: css

Menu on my site is opening up even when my cursor is not on top of it.

Here is the picture;
http://www.image-share.com/upload/1395/204.jpg

Go to menu item "About" from down. You will see that it's opening up before you come on it.

website; http://goo.gl/rnhJ7

Comment: Solved ! use visibility: hidden; and onhover visibility: visible;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you hide it with opacity.. That means that the submenu retains its space in the page, and once you mouseover the container it increases the opacity..

---

Edit in your CSS the rules as

```
#nmenu li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility:visible;
    transition-delay:0s; /* add the vendor specific versions.. -moz- -webkit- ..*/
}

#nmenu li > ul {
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#nmenu ul {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s; /* add the vendor specific versions.. -moz- -webkit- ..*/
}
```

Comment: I understood very clearly now. I want to give that effect to that object. then I need to move it when its opacity 0 it should be somewhere else right ?

Comment: @user, yes exactly.. but i am not sure you can do that with CSS

Comment: When I wanted it to not to be visible it's visibility: hidden; and on hover position its visibility: visible;. It solved the problem. You gave me very nice clue =) Thank you !

Comment: @Reis, i came to the same conclusion .. have a look at the updated answer with code..